# how to display the image in the button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

please help to fix the script.

the problem is that my script for some reason displays blank buttons. and I need to have in each button corresponding image.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os, tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

size = 128, 128

for infile in glob.glob("images/*.gif"):
    Im = Image.open(infile)
    pointerIm = Im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkinter.Button(root, image=pointerIm).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should pass `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of `Image`.
- `thumbnail` method does not return anything; It modifies image inplace.
- You need to keep references to `PhotoImage` object. Otherwise it will be garbage collected.

  - In the following code I append PhotoImage objects to `images` list to keep reference.

---

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob, os, tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

size = 128, 128

images = []
for infile in glob.glob("images/*.gif"):
    Im = Image.open(infile)
    Im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Im)
    images.append(photo_image)
    tkinter.Button(root, image=photo_image).pack()

root.mainloop()
```